# XMLHttpRequest and Binding a Callback not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, xmlhttprequest, function-binding

I have a simple `get` function using `XMLHttpRequest` which accepts a callback parameter. The plan is to invoke the callback on the `onload` event handler.

Here is a simplified version:

```
get(url,doit);

function doit(data) {
    alert(data)
}
function post(url,callback) {
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload=function() {                     //  Version 1
        callback(xhr.response)
    }
    xhr.onload=callback.bind(xhr,xhr.response); //  Version 2
    xhr.open('get',url,true);
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

The callback function has one parameter, `data` which is supposed to be the response from the Ajax Call.

I have 2 versions of invoking the callback:

1. Version 1 simply calls the callback inside the event handler function.
2. Version 2 uses `bind` to do the same; `this` is set to the `xhr` object, while the `xhr.response` is sent as the argument.

When I use Version 1, everything works as expected. When I use Version 2, the `data` parameter is empty.

I thought I knew `XMLHttpRequest` and `.bind()` reasonably well, but I cannot work out why the second version is empty. What is (not) happening here?

**Comment**

Thanks to the answers, I think I have it.

`.bind()` is executed immediately with the *current* value of `xhr.responseText`, which, at this stage, is nothing.

It appears that the first Version is preferable if I need to respond with a *future* value.

Thanks all.

Comment: When you execute `.bind(xhr,xhr.response)` there isn't any response yet -> `xhr.response === undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `callback.bind` will be executed immediately. And at the time it is executed, `xhr.responseText` is obviously not available since the request has not been completed yet. You can try this to see the result.

```
function doit(data) {
    alert(data, this.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior of `bind`: when parameter is binded, the binded value is the referenced object, or the primitive value at that moment.

Here is a simple code snippet:

```
function operate(callback) {
  let a = {
    display: 'AAA'
  };
  setTimeout(callback.bind('ThisObj', a.display), 1000);
  a.display = 'AAA222';
}

operate(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The printed result is: `AAA`, as `a.display` is binded and `a.display` is a primitive type (String) -- the value at the bind moment (`AAA`) is passed.

**This is just what happened for `xhr.response`, as its type is String.**

---

However, if an object is bind as parameter, that object's reference will be passed, which means the binded function would get the latest value:

```
function operate(callback) {
  let tmp = {
    t: 'AAA'
  };
  let a = {
    display: tmp
  };
  setTimeout(callback.bind('ThisObj', a.display), 1000);
  tmp.t = 'AAA222';
}

operate(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The printed result is: `{ t: 'AAA222' }`

Please note: if variable `a` in the above example changes its value to another object, the binded reference value does not change (still the previous referenced object):

```
function operate(callback) {
  let a = {
    display: 'AAA'
  };
  setTimeout(callback.bind('ThisObj', a), 1000);
  a = {
    display: 'AAA222'
  };
}

operate(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The printed result is: `{ display: 'AAA' }`